# java.lang.IllegalStateException: This operation is not allowed on a closed folder

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure, oauth-2.0

```
store.connect("outlook.office365.com", "email@bussness.com", token);
            
            Folder folder = store.getFolder("INBOX");
            Message[] messages = folder.getMessages();
            
            for(Message msg : messages) {
                System.out.println(msg);
            }
```

I am trying to read the messages of an email associated with a javaMail in Microsoft Azure when trying to extract the information I get the following oauth2 protocols error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: This operation is not allowed on a closed folder
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.checkOpened(IMAPFolder.java:478)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.getMessages(IMAPFolder.java:1856)
    at com.communication.quickstart.ExecuteTwo.main(ExecuteTwo.java:57)
```

at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.checkOpened(IMAPFolder.java:478)

Comment: The error message seems pretty straight forward. Have you tried opening the folder as the message suggests: https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/index.html?com/sun/mail/imap/IMAPFolder.html ?

Comment: Right now the same thing is happening to me with my application, I don't know, you already solved the ImapFolder problem.